# Importing component, element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying import my `Search` component but keep getting the above error:

```
import {Search} from '../components/Search';
import {filteredVideo, initSearch} from '../actions/videos';
import StyledText from '../components/StyledText';
const DrawerHeader = props => {
  const {
    navigation,
    route: {name},
  } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        ....
      <Search {...props} />
    </>
  );
};

export default DrawerHeader;
```

Search:

```
const Search = props => {
  const {
    navigation: {navigate},
    route: {name},
    value,
  } = props;

  ....

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text onPress={() => onPress(item)} style={style.itemStyle}>
        {item.title}
      </Text>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View>
        {name == 'Home' || name == 'Video Episodes' ? (
        <SearchBar
          round
          containerStyle={styles.containerStyle}
          inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
          inputContainerStyle={{
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}
          icon={iconStyle}
          onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEdit}
          searchIcon={{size: 18}}
          onChangeText={text => SearchFilterFunction(text)}
          onClear={text => SearchFilterFunction('')}
          placeholder="Type Here..."
          value="hello"
        />
      ) : null}
      {name == 'Home' ? (
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={search.videos}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            contentContainerStyle={{overflow: 'hidden'}}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={separator}
          />
        </View>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Any ideas?

Error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a default export
so change this

```
import {Search} from '../components/Search';
```

to

```
import Search from '../components/Search';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import Search from '../components/Search';
```

or

```js
export { Search }
```